# How does Hotspot work for its authentication?

Tags: login, session, wifi

I'd like to know how an Hotspot can understand that a user leave the Network? How can it understand that the user closed his session?
Is there any solution that server can understand the user became off?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem with some existing equipment?  If so, it is a much better idea to tell us what equipment you have, how it's configured, and how you can reproduce the problem you have.  As it stands, the situation is rather unclear.

Comment: In fact I have a problem with my system (Squid Session). I want to know how can I understand once user leave then terminate his session. You can see my problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/559942/squid-session-user-authentication